# Is there a way to clone a table in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to clone a table in Kusto exactly so it has all the extents of the original table? Even if it's not possible to have extents retained , at least is there a performant way to copy a table to a new table. I tried the following:-

```
.set new_table <| existing_table;
```

It was running forever and got timeout error. Is there way to copy so the Kusto engine recognizes that this is just a dump copy so instead of using Kusto engine, it will just do a simple blob copy from back-end and simply point the new table to the copied blob thus bypassing the whole Kusto processing route?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** Copying schema and data of one table to another is possible using the command you mentioned (another option to copy the data is to [export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage) its content into cloud storage, then ingest the result storage artifacts using Kusto's [ingestion API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest) or a tool that uses it, e.g. [LightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/lightingest) or [ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/azure-data-factory))

Of course, if the source table has a lot of data, then you would want to split this command into multiple ones, each dealing with a subset of the source data (which you can 'partition', for example, by time).

Below is just one example (it obviously depends on how much data you have in the source table):

```
.set-or-append [async] new_table <| existing_table | where ingestion_time() > X and ingestion_time() < X + 1h

.set-or-append [async] new_table <| existing_table | where ingestion_time() >= X+1h and ingestion_time() < X + 2h

...
```

Note that the `async` is optional, and is to avoid the potential client-side-timeout (default after 10 minutes). the command itself continues to run on the backend for up to a non-configurable timout of 60 mins (though it's strongly advised to avoid such long-running commands, e.g. by performing the "partitioning" mentioned above).

**2.** To your other question: There's no option to copy data between tables without re-ingesting the data (an extent / data shard currently can't belong to more than 1 table).

**3.** If you need to "duplicate" data being ingestion into table T1 continuously into table T2, and both T1 and T2 are in the same database, you can achieve that using an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/updatepolicy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.create table based-on` command to create a new table based on another table. Here is an example:

```
.create table new_table_name based-on reference_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on how large your source table is.  It sounds like yours is large.

For a table under 1 gig, I use:

.set table  <|

I prefer this method instead of ".set-or-append" since it will fail if I've already run this query, as opposed to duplicating data if I have.  If the table is too large, you will need to copy portions of it at a time.  I use ADF when this happens because I have some logic already tucked away there for this kind of scenario.

I'd create a step that runs a command in ADF to pull each extent (reasonably sized chunks of data that can be copied without timing out) from the table you're interested in

.set a new table with the same schema
.show table MyOldTable extents

and create a foreach loop,

```
foreach extent 

.append MyNewTable <|
MyOldTable
| where extent_id() == ExtentIdInForEachLoop
```